# Right -angled triangle perimeter question

Tags: geometry

A right-angled triangle has an area of 5. The altitude perpendicular to the hypotenuse has a length of 2. Calculate the perimeter of the triangle.
[image]

I could not get the area of the triangle to be 5 so can anyone show me where I went wrong?

Comment: the hyponethuse should have a length of 5, not 4

Comment: Can you at least calculate the hypotenuse?

Comment: @Alessandro how did you get 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide an alternative to [amWhy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732518/right-angled-triangle-perimeter-question#answer-732531).

Let $a$ and $b$ be the sides of the triangle and $c$ is the hypotenuse. Let $h$ be the height relative to the hypotenuse.

$$area=\frac{1}{2}hc=5$$ so that $c=5$

In the same way $area=\frac{1}{2}ab=5$ so that $ab=10$

$$a^2+b^2=5^2=25$$
$$(a+b)^2-2ab=25$$
$$(a+b)^2-20=25$$
$$a+b=\sqrt{45}=3\sqrt{5}$$
Combining the last equation with $$ab=10$$ one obtain
$$a^2-3\sqrt{5}a+10=0$$
Thus $a=\sqrt{5}$ and $b=2\sqrt{5}$

The perimeter is $a+b+c=5+3\sqrt{5}$

Comment: You don't even need to calculate $a$ and $b$ separately. Once you got that $a + b = 3\sqrt{5}$ you can immediately say that $a + b + c = 3\sqrt{5} + 5$.

Comment: @ElThor Of course, but I wanted to use the quadratic equation to find $a$ in case he'll be asked to find it in the future.